# hide close button in ie toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

i'v made toolbar for IE, and want to hide leftside-close-button. What is the way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add full window snap?

Comment: You intend for your users to be unable to close your toolbar? I have a feeling you should take your spyware development questions someplace else.

Comment: no ))) no spyware, just analog firefox toolbar havenot such button and tolbars looks differents ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove or obscure the close button, your toolbar will be blocked from loading in IE because it violates the Internet Explorer browser add-on guidelines.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973764 for details.